# Trying to handle the leftBarButton in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationitem

My UINavigationBar is not handling properly.

I would like it to Navigate back to the last UIViewController, though i get a black screen when pressing the leftBAckButton and not the previous UIViewcontroller.
View
Controller.m `viewDidLoad`

```
 UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"&" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(home:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton;
```

This is the `-(void)home:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender`

```
-(void)home:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Though i feel this is correct i receive this when pressing the button

[image: Nav Error]

As you can see the navigationbar seems to disappear and it never navigates to the previous view controller.

When using `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

I receive! this on the UI

[image: blackScreen]

What is causing this and how can i fix it?

Comment: To go back one level you use `popViewControllerAnimated:`.

Comment: I tried that as well and it goes to an all black view with a UINavigationBar

Comment: Is that screen shot the "before" or the "after"? Because I still see a navigation bar (it has not disappeared). Also, is that your actual code up there? Can you format it in a way that makes it a little more readable or in a way that more visibly separates code from different sections of your implementation file?

Comment: I updated the code, this is the after though, the navigation bar loses its back button as well as the title when presenting both popViewControllerAnimated: & popToRootViewControllerAnimated:

Comment: Is your view controller actually pushed onto a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: @AdamPro13 What do you mean by that?

Comment: Meaning if your view was never pushed onto a navigation controller in the first place, you don't have anything to do the actual popping. Can you either set a breakpoint or log what the value for `self.navigationController` is before you call the pop?

Comment: i get a UINavigationController in memory : 0x10b98d7a0

Comment: @AdamPro13 It returns an object, its not Nil.....do you know what would be causing this?